# How to get data from ICM-20948

Tags: accelerometer, gyroscope, compass

If you have an expirience in working with ICM-20948, give me answers to the questions.
1) How to read data from WHO_AM_I register.
2) How to get data from magnetometer registers.
I need some examples of working code.
I need only code, not reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

There is several code exemple on github web site.    Invensense have also exemples in their developer section.